# Multi-solvent recrystallization to extract solute from glycerol?

Tags: solubility, home-experiment, purification, recrystallization

I have compound A contaminated with impurity B. Recrystallization in water would not yield pure compound A since impurity B is less soluble in it. The only solvent in which substances A and B have opposite solubility is glycerol. Compound A is soluble in it while impurity B is insoluble.

I would propose my first step to be heating the glycerol to minimize the amount of solvent needed to fully dilute compound A. I would then filter the solution to have my purified compound A in glycerol solution (impurity B would remain in filter).

As far as I have heard though, glycerol is not as easy to boil as water, being similar to cooking oil. Unfortunately, I don't have a vacuum distillation apparatus to extract the glycerol without caramelizing it.

I was thinking of slowly add anhydrous ethanol to (purified compound A + glycerol), since compound A is insoluble in it. I would expect multi-solvent recrystallization to occur as I add ethanol and lower the mixture temperature.

Would it work and does it seem to be the easiest method of purification at home?

For the curious: $A = \ce{KNO3}, B = \ce{K2SO4}$.
No, I don't want the $\ce{KNO3}$ to make a bomb, but to make a sugar rocket for model rocketry.

Comment: That's a lot of thinking for making sugar rocket...

Comment: @Mithoron I have heard it might work well even when contaminated with 7% K2SO4, what I have now. But  I would like to test with pure KNO3 to see if I can extract some extra juice from it.

Comment: Well actually you can make a bomb with only sugar... so don't worry about your question.

Comment: As an inverse to recrystallisation; you could add varying quantities of water to the same mass of impure solid and experiment with varying temperatures. The goal here is not to dissolve everything, but to dissolve up more A and leave B behind. i. e. A warm reslurry. When you get your best result, filter B off warm.

Comment: @Beerhunter Best result would be at 100C, and it has a mass ratio of 91% between KNO3 and K2SO4. My KNO3 is already at 93% in the mixture. I would actually lose purity.
Unless you are supposing the K2SO4 solubility would be reduced by the KNO3 presence, and not the opposite. Could you precise further?

Comment: "Recrystallization in water would not yield pure compound A since impurity B is less soluble in it". So maybe try a reslurry where A is preferentially dissolved over B.

Comment: @Beerhunter That is what I am trying to do with the glycerol. The problem is that after filtering insoluble B from the glycerol, how do I remove the glycerol to get pure A? I don't have a vacuum distillation apparatus to prevent the caramelization of glycerol to boil it.
I could technically cool it down, but its melting point is higher than 15C. I don't think the recrystalization will yield more than a few grams of KNO3.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, so try your proposal out on a test sample. Glycerol seems better than water for the separation, but you have the downstream processing issue of obtaining your product. If you used water and sacrificed some yield, you might have a better chance of precipitating and drying (if required) your product. I'm not saying it'd be better, just an alternative. A reslurry is easier to perform than embarking on a recrystallisation.